# Can WebhookResponse send a Basic Card?

Tags: c#, google-api, dialogflow-es

I'm developing an action and I want to return a basic card with information from a fullfilment webhook. I can return plain text with no problem, using WebhookResponse class for preparing the data before sending it. I did also create the basic card using BasicCard class.

I noticed the response the WebhookResponse creates is diferent from the example responses available on google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/rich-responses). I was wandering if there's a new version I missed? Or if this isn't at all possible using this class?
"Rich responses" are the kind of response I want to return, but I can't figure out where that locks in with the WebhookResponse class.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
webhookResp = new WebhookResponse
{
    FulfillmentText = @"Fullfilment Phrase. ",
    FulfillmentMessages = 
    { new Intent.Types.Message
        { SimpleResponses = new Intent.Types.Message.Types.SimpleResponses
            { SimpleResponses_ =
                { new Intent.Types.Message.Types.SimpleResponse
                    {
                        DisplayText = @"Text",
                        TextToSpeech = @"The speech",
                        Ssml = $"<speak>The speech</speak>"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
      new Intent.Types.Message
        { BasicCard = new Intent.Types.Message.Types.BasicCard
            {
                Title = @"Card Title",
                Subtitle = @"Card Subtitle",
                FormattedText = @"Card Information",
                Buttons =
                { new Button
                    {
                        Title = @"Url",
                        OpenUriAction = new OpenUriAction
                        {
                            Uri = "url"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    Source = "my-app"
};
```

And the json received by the Assistant:

```
{
  "fulfillmentText": "Fullfilment Phrase. ",
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "messageCase": 7,
      "text": null,
      "image": null,
      "quickReplies": null,
      "card": null,
      "payload": null,
      "simpleResponses": {
        "simpleResponses_": [
          {
            "textToSpeech": "The speech",
            "ssml": "<speak>The speech</speak>",
            "displayText": "Text"
          }
        ]
      },
      "basicCard": null,
      "suggestions": null,
      "linkOutSuggestion": null,
      "listSelect": null,
      "carouselSelect": null,
      "browseCarouselCard": null,
      "tableCard": null,
      "mediaContent": null,
      "platform": 0
    },
    {
      "messageCase": 8,
      "text": null,
      "image": null,
      "quickReplies": null,
      "card": null,
      "payload": null,
      "simpleResponses": null,
      "basicCard": {
        "title": "Card Title",
        "subtitle": "Card Subtitle",
        "formattedText": "Card Information",
        "image": null,
        "buttons": [
          {
            "title": "Url",
            "openUriAction": {
              "uri": "url"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "suggestions": null,
      "linkOutSuggestion": null,
      "listSelect": null,
      "carouselSelect": null,
      "browseCarouselCard": null,
      "tableCard": null,
      "mediaContent": null,
      "platform": 0
    }
  ],
  "source": "my-app",
  "payload": null,
  "outputContexts": [],
  "followupEven
  "sessionEntityTypes": []
}
```

Thank you in advance for trying to help.
If any information more needed please say :)

páris

Comment: To be clear - are you specifically developing this for the Assistant? What library are you using?

Comment: Yes, for the Assistant. I'm using using Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2 and Google.Protobuf, is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2` package is to use Dialogflow as a client - not to use for Dialogflow fulfillment. So the `WebhookResponse` is usually *created for you* based on the response that comes from the server. You're not expected to create it yourself.

To send a response from your webhook, you will need to generate the JSON and return it as the reply from your webhook.

In addition, the `BasicCard` that Dialogflow refers to is not the same as the `Card` that is used by Actions on Google. Dialogflow has a generic "Card" that it represents, but it does not translate this into the Actions on Google "Card".

Comment: Maybe it's my lack of knowledge of the language, but I don't think creating json objects like the ones google awaits, in C#, is that fun to play with.. that's why I was using the WebhookResponse class to ease the work a bit. But I'll try to make a simple one work and go from there.

Comment: Unfortunately creating the json objects yourself is probably your only option as there isn't a library for c# and dialoge flow.   Using something like ngrok can help you spy on the messages sent back and forth via node as the documentation isn't updated enough to use it to find the json format for requests