# Why can't Google Actions receive my BasicCard?

Tags: c#, json, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

In sequence of my prior [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63078459/can-webhookresponse-send-a-basic-card) about the WebhookResponse class I have a new one:

I tried another approach:

```
webhookResp = new WebhookResponse
{
    FulfillmentText = @"TEXT",
    FulfillmentMessages =
    {
        new Message
        {
            SimpleResponses = new Message.Types.SimpleResponses
            {
                SimpleResponses_ =
                {
                    { new Message.Types.SimpleResponse
                        {
                            DisplayText = ans.Phrase,
                            TextToSpeech = ans.Phrase,
                            Ssml = $"<speak>{ans.Phrase}</speak>"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            BasicCard = new Message.Types.BasicCard
            {
                Title = Constants.help_title,
                Subtitle = Constants.help_answer,
                FormattedText = ans.Phrase,
                Image = new Message.Types.Image
                {
                    ImageUri = "https://example.com/images/example.png",
                    AccessibilityText = "Image Text"
                },
                Buttons =
                {
                    new Message.Types.BasicCard.Types.Button
                    {
                        Title = @"Call",
                        OpenUriAction = new Message.Types.BasicCard.Types.Button.Types.OpenUriAction
                        {
                            Uri = "<your visit url>"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            Platform = Message.Types.Platform.ActionsOnGoogle
        }
    },
    Source = "my-webhook",
};
```

Json received by the Assistant:

```
{
  "conversationToken": "[]",
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "expectedInputs": [
    {
      "inputPrompt": {
        "richInitialPrompt": {
          "items": [
            {
              "basicCard": {
                "title": "Help",
                "subtitle": "I can connect you to the Cloogy team. Try calling them. ",
                "formattedText": "I can connect you to the Cloogy team. Try calling them. ",
                "image": {
                  "url": "https://example.com/images/example.png",
                  "accessibilityText": "Image Text"
                },
                "buttons": [
                  {
                    "title": "Call",
                    "openUrlAction": {
                      "url": "<your visit url>"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "possibleIntents": [
        {
          "intent": "assistant.intent.action.TEXT"
        }
      ],
      "speechBiasingHints": [
        "$plug_state",
        "$plug_id"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "message": "Success (200)"
    },
    "queryMatchInfo": {
      "queryMatched": true,
      "intent": "749c5c8e-08ab-4474-b2aa-023143a119b3"
    },
    "delegatedRequest": {
      "delegatedRequest": "{\n  \"responseId\": \"e0744f37-7ad2-476a-938f-58434e8f362c-0820055c\",\n  \"queryResult\": {\n    \"queryText\": \"help\",\n    \"parameters\": {\n    },\n    \"allRequiredParamsPresent\": true,\n    \"outputContexts\": [{\n      \"name\": \"projects/helper-fklyfp/agent/sessions/SESSION/contexts/actions_capability_audio_output\"\n    }, {\n      \"name\": \"projects/helper-fklyfp/agent/sessions/SESSION/contexts/actions_capability_media_response_audio\"\n    }, {\n      \"name\": \"projects/helper-fklyfp/agent/sessions/SESSION/contexts/actions_capability_account_linking\"\n    }, {\n      \"name\": \"projects/helper-fklyfp/agent/sessions/SESSION/contexts/actions_capability_screen_output\"\n    }, {\n      \"name\": \"projects/helper-fklyfp/agent/sessions/SESSION/contexts/actions_capability_web_browser\"\n    }, {\n      \"name\": \"projects/helper-fklyfp/agent/sessions/SESSION/contexts/google_assistant_input_type_keyboard\"\n    }, {\n      \"name\": \"projects/helper-fklyfp/agent/sessions/SESSION/contexts/__system_counters__\",\n      \"parameters\": {\n        \"no-input\": 0.0,\n        \"no-match\": 0.0\n      }\n    }],\n    \"intent\": {\n      \"name\": \"projects/helper-fklyfp/agent/intents/749c5c8e-08ab-4474-b2aa-023143a119b3\",\n      \"displayName\": \"ask help\"\n    },\n    \"intentDetectionConfidence\": 0.80672485,\n    \"languageCode\": \"en\"\n  },\n  \"originalDetectIntentRequest\": {\n    \"source\": \"google\",\n    \"version\": \"2\",\n    \"payload\": {\n      \"user\": {\n        \"accessToken\": \"ACCESS_TOKEN\",\n        \"locale\": \"en-US\",\n        \"lastSeen\": \"2020-07-29T15:10:16Z\",\n        \"userVerificationStatus\": \"VERIFIED\"\n      },\n      \"conversation\": {\n        \"conversationId\": \"SESSION\",\n        \"type\": \"ACTIVE\",\n        \"conversationToken\": \"[]\"\n      },\n      \"inputs\": [{\n        \"intent\": \"actions.intent.TEXT\",\n        \"rawInputs\": [{\n          \"inputType\": \"KEYBOARD\",\n          \"query\": \"help\"\n        }],\n        \"arguments\": [{\n          \"name\": \"text\",\n          \"rawText\": \"help\",\n          \"textValue\": \"help\"\n        }]\n      }],\n      \"surface\": {\n        \"capabilities\": [{\n          \"name\": \"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"\n        }, {\n          \"name\": \"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"\n        }, {\n          \"name\": \"actions.capability.ACCOUNT_LINKING\"\n        }, {\n          \"name\": \"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"\n        }, {\n          \"name\": \"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"\n        }]\n      },\n      \"isInSandbox\": true,\n      \"availableSurfaces\": [{\n        \"capabilities\": [{\n          \"name\": \"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"\n        }, {\n          \"name\": \"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"\n        }, {\n          \"name\": \"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"\n        }]\n      }],\n      \"requestType\": \"SIMULATOR\"\n    }\n  },\n  \"session\": \"projects/helper-fklyfp/agent/sessions/SESSION\"\n}"
    },
    "delegatedResponse": {
      "delegatedResponse": "{\"fulfillmentText\":\"TEXT\",\"fulfillmentMessages\":[{\"messageCase\":8,\"text\":null,\"image\":null,\"quickReplies\":null,\"card\":null,\"payload\":null,\"simpleResponses\":null,\"basicCard\":{\"title\":\"Help\",\"subtitle\":\"I can connect you to the Cloogy team. Try calling them. \",\"formattedText\":\"I can connect you to the Cloogy team. Try calling them. \",\"image\":{\"imageUri\":\"https://example.com/images/example.png\",\"accessibilityText\":\"Image Text\"},\"buttons\":[{\"title\":\"Call\",\"openUriAction\":{\"uri\":\"\\u003Cyour visit url\\u003E\"}}]},\"suggestions\":null,\"linkOutSuggestion\":null,\"listSelect\":null,\"carouselSelect\":null,\"browseCarouselCard\":null,\"tableCard\":null,\"mediaContent\":null,\"platform\":8}],\"source\":\"my-webhook\",\"payload\":null,\"outputContexts\":[],\"followupEventInput\":null,\"sessionEntityTypes\":[]}"
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Device Output]

I guess there's something wrong with de delegatedResponse field, but I don't know how to fix it, beacause I don't explicitly fill it in. (or at least I think I don't). Why is the output given by GoogleActions not a BasicCard?

Thanks for any help in advance,

páris

Answer (score 1):

That error is a broad message meaning it couldn't translate the response from your webhook into a valid response to Actions on Google. In this case, it actually looks like there was no `SimpleResponse` sent back, even tho it looks like you tried to specify one.

The `WebhookResponse` object really isn't intended for this purpose, and I'm not sure how it is serializing into JSON for the response.